# CodeIgniter version update - Query builder's limit() producing empty array

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, query-builder

To be clear, I don't have any previous experience with CodeIgniter at all.

Was assigned with an old website where the CI version got recently updated to the latest one and some of the loops aren't displaying anything. Noticed the problem starts with a query builder line where the `limit()` function is used.

in the `Home.php` controller, the `__construct()` function does:

```
$this->load->orm('db_et_comu_news', 'news');
```

and after this, the `index()` function has:

```
$this->_data['news'] = $this->news->where('status',1)->where('id_et_cat_comu_news',2)->order_by('data','DESC')->limit(7)->find_all();
```

This worked in the past CI version and returned a perfectly working array of results but, after the update, all I get is an empty array. If I remove `limit()`from the query making it like this:

```
$this->_data['news'] = $this->news->where('status',1)->where('id_et_cat_comu_news',2)->order_by('data','DESC')->find_all();
```

The query returns a good healthy array, but not limiting my rows to 7, as desired.

I've checked the CI 3.1.3 documentation and the function *seems* to be correctly applied. Can anyone help me spot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your controller code with this.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['news'] = $this->news();

        if(!empty($data['news']))
        {
           foreach($data['news'] as $objects)
           {
           echo $objects->data;
           }
        }

    }

    function news()
    {
        $query = $this
                ->db
                ->select('*')
                ->from('db_et_comu_news')
                ->where('status',1)
                ->where('id_et_cat_comu_news',"2")
                ->order_by("data", "DESC")
                ->limit(7)
                ->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return $query->result();  // return an array of objects
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I ended up coming to this conclusion by myself too and hoped I could use a simpler answer since I'll need to do this in a ton of areas, seems it's the right answer tho, thanks for helping me reaffirm this